# how to dry up sass mixin code with before and after blocks?

Tags: css, sass, dry, mixins

I have the following scss code.

```
  @if $position == bottom {
    &:after {
      height: $triangle-width;
      width: $triangle-width;
      content:"";
      position:absolute;
      margin-top: -$triangle-width/2 -$stroke-width;
    }
  }

  @if $position == top {
    &:before {
      height: $triangle-width;
      width: $triangle-width;
      content:"";
      position:absolute;
      margin-bottom: -$triangle-width/2 -$stroke-width;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, there is some code which is duplicated. I was wondering if there is a way to dry it up. I tried to put it into a own class but that didn't seem to work somehow. Any ideas? I could make a mixin in a mixin but that seems ab it too much overhead in my opinion. What do you think?

Comment: Why not just make one mixin and pass before/after and top/bottom as arguments. Seems much simpler than an if statement.

Comment: Good input thanks, I will try that. If I would pass before/after I think I might not even need the top/bottom arguments.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you are doing here, you really shouldn't worry about your mixin...  the output is all that matters.  Here is an example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/57e977a54b42c76961c2

Comment: @SeanStopnik yes you got it right, the dry up was more meant for maintainability as I have some more properties in both classes (left them out for briefty). So whenever I want to change some of the design, I have to change it in two places - or I have to use variables for every property.

Comment: If you'd like, you can send me the full mixin code, and once seeing it, maybe I can rework it a bit. It's hard to get the full scope without seeing the code in full. Totally up to you. I do love a good mixin challenge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the best way to make things DRY is to break the common parts out into mixins and build those up into larger mixins. This is exactly how Compass and most other frameworks do this. See the [Compass list mixins](https://github.com/Compass/compass/tree/stable/core/stylesheets/compass/typography/lists) for example.

```scss
@mixin base-triangle($triangle-width) {
  height: $triangle-width;
  width: $triangle-width;
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
}

@mixin triangle($position, $triangle-width: 4, $stroke-width: 4) {
  @if $position == bottom {
    &:after {
      @include base-triangle($triangle-width);
      margin-top: -$triangle-width/2 -$stroke-width;
    }
  }

  @if $position == top {
    &:before {
      @include base-triangle($triangle-width);
      margin-bottom: -$triangle-width/2 -$stroke-width;
    }
  }
}

.foo {
  @include triangle("top", 8px, 8px);
}

.bar {
  @include triangle("bottom");
}
```

Compiles to:

```css
.foo:before {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: -12px;
}

.bar:after {
  height: 4;
  width: 4;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -6;
}
```

Comment: definitely the most robust solution for keeping it DRY. It allows the use of adding position top:0; or bottom:0; without defining both. And therefore solves my dilemma

Answer (score 3):

The best way to use this sort of mixin is to leave the `:before` or `:after` out of the mixin, and just use the mixin in the pseudo class of choice directly.  This cleans up the mixin, as well as removes any ties to if/else logic.

Mixin Example:

```
@mixin yourMixinName($position, $size, $stroke) {
    position: absolute;
    width: $size;
    height: $size;
    margin-#{$position}: -($size / 2) - $stroke;
    content: '';
}
```

Usage Example:

```
.test {

    &:before {
        @include yourMixinName(top, 20px, 20px);
    }
}

.test-2 {

    &:after {
        @include yourMixinName(bottom, 20px, 20px);
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution definitely works in the users case.  BUT you are repeating too much. If you have to use this 50 times, you've re-written &:before or &:after 50 times. When you could keep it DRY by using a callback mixin.

Comment: One other warning for potential readers (as I came looking for a refresher myself). When using position absolute many people also define top:{#} or bottom:{#}. But if you define both you won't get the same effect. So you would need a place to only define top:0 or only define bottom:0; Which means another set of 50 repeated lines in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

These SASS variables are just some random variables, to be used in this example.

```
$position : top ;
$triangle-width : 100px;
$stroke-width : 100px;
```

SASS mixin to clearly encapsulate logic in one place. And IF-ELSE are left out, so that it can be used at more than one place.

```
@mixin before_after($margin-side,$before-after){
&:#{$before-after} {
      height: $triangle-width;
      width: $triangle-width;
      content:"";
      position:absolute;
      margin-#{$margin-side}: -$triangle-width/2 -$stroke-width;
    }

}
```

You can combine mixin with IF-ELSE statement.

```
p{
    @if $position == top {

        @include before_after(bottom,before);
    }@else{
        @include before_after(top,after);
    }
}
```

Or you can use it without any IF-ELSE too.

```
p{
@include before_after(bottom,before);
}

div{
@include before_after(top,before);
}
```

**PS** : The edit are made to add extra few text lines so that **@Sean Stopnik** can understand what is going on in here.
And my answer is supposed to provide just a base, on which the person who asked the question can build his own solution. Not to document each and every variable use and spoon-feeding.
**Just a response to Sean Stopnik comments**

- Please provide meaningful comments only, that helps to improve the
  answer.
- Or If you have anything else to add to improve the answer.
- If you have  better answer then post it.
- Don't spam comment box, Because when people come looking for answer
  then they read comments too, to get better understanding of the
  answer.
- And you are basically wasting everybody's time.

Comment: This clearly is incorrect. You completely bypassed the if statement.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Yes I did it on purpose.. I did not understand.. how it helps to generate only `before` or `after` in a css.. It is not like CSS will get generated on runtime..

Comment: Still not right. Your answer would generate a before AND after... That's what I was pointing out.

Comment: Still not right.  The if/else needs to be in the mixin... not when calling the mixin.  Right now you are saying if $position == top....  what $position?  What $top?  If that is outside the mixin, what are you referencing? Need to put the if/else in the mixin itself.